# Immutable compact class's copy function for Genie

Tags: genie

This code I translate from
[Vala's Memory Management Explained](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ReferenceHandling)

section:
**Immutable compact classes with a copy function**

I have try to run that vala's code. It work as aspected.

But I have some trouble now.

1: compile

> error: syntax error, expected declaration  but got `[' with previous end of line [Immutable]

2: I remove all attributes

> error: Return with value in void function
>
> return new Foo ()

3: give it a return value

```
construct copy (): Foo
```

> error: syntax error, expected identifier
>
> ```
> construct copy (): Foo
> ```

my code:

```
[indent = 4]

[Compact]
[Immutable]
[CCode (copy_function = "foo_copy")]
class Foo
    def method ()
        print "METHOD"

    construct copy ()
        return new Foo ()


init
    var foo = new Foo ()
    foo.method ()
    var bar = foo
```

How can I translate that to Genie correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have confused the return value, `Foo`, in Vala with a constructor. In Genie the code would be:

```
[indent = 4]

[Compact, Immutable, CCode (copy_function = "foo_copy")]
class Foo
    def method ()
        pass

    def copy ():Foo
        return new Foo ()

init
    var foo = new Foo ()
    foo.method ()
    var bar = foo
```

Multiple attributes should be comma separated.